# Scala: join iterators with values in a wrapper

Tags: scala, collections, iterator, flatten

I have the following types: `A`, `B` and `C`, so `B <: A` and `C <: A`

I need to get the `Iterator[A]` that works like this:

- If the current value is of type `B`, then return `B`
- If the current value is of type `C`, then invoke function `parse(c: C) : Iterator[B]` and then use this iterator until it exhausts. Then continue with the value from the "parent" iterator.

What is the best way to do so in Scala?

Comment: Should we presume that if the value is type `A` but not `B` or `C` then the value should be discarded?  Or are you happy for it to throw MatchError for you to catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pattern matching and flatMap:

```
val itA: Iterator[A] = // ...
val itB: Iterator[B] = itA.flatMap(a => a match {
  case b: B => Iterator(b)
  case c: C => parse(c)
})
```

Comment: The technique is correct but won't this example throw `MatchError` if a value in `itA` is of type `A` but not 'B` or `C`?  I realise the OP didn't specify the desired behaviour in that case.